# C++ use included class from a header under another identifier

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, alias, declaration

I'm facing an issue where a declared class name from an included (foreign) header file collides with the a declared class name of my own header file.
But basically I want to compose my class with the included class.
In Golang a solution would be to use a functionality called [Import Declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations).

- How can I achieve that:

  - without renaming my own declaration (or modifying the consumers of my own declaration)?
  - and without using inheritance (prefer composition over inheritance)?
  - and without altering the foreign code?
- And what is the right terminology for this?

I've been searching already several threads and forums, but can't come up with a solution.
What I tried till now (and what can be seen in the code beneath) is to surround the included header with a custom namespace. But this leads to nasty linking problems (see below), when I'm accessing methods of the included class.
I'm kinda new to C++, so I'd be very happy about elaborated explanations, on how to achieve this.

**The foreign header file ("some/sensor.h"):**

```cpp
class Sensor {
 public:
  Sensor(unsigned char a, unsigned char b);
 /*some definitions...*/
};
```

**My declaration ("sensor.h"):**

```cpp
namespace Lib {
#include "some/sensor.h"
};

class Sensor {
 private:
  Lib::Sensor s; /* use foreign object as member */
 public:
  Sensor();
  void init(unsigned char p);
};
```

**Receiving Errors like:**

```
In function `Sensor::init(unsigned char)':
  undefined reference to `Lib::Sensor::Sensor(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
  /* ...and so on... */
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You can't put just the class definition inside a namespace; you also need to define the member functions inside it. You're on the right track, but you need to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: I'm trying to redeclare the class of the external library, so that I can use that very same classname in my own code (because of the fact that it is most intuitive).
So how can I make this happen?

Comment: There are two ways you can make this happen: 1) modify the library, or 2) convince the author of the library to change it. Or, you can do what everyone else does – either rename your class or put it in a namespace – and get on with your life. Use `using mynamespace::Sensor;` if you want to save a few keystrokes when you're using your own class.

Comment: @molbdnilo ok, got your point! Thank you for clarifying. Obviously I will follow your advice. It was just for me to fully understand the matter (and the way the language works). I will create an issue for the library authors, but for now I will go on with your recommendation. 

Comment: @m0r0n It may be intentional if the library is in some way standard or fundamental. In that case the library might consider the global namespace reserved for itself and will probably ask you to use a namespace for your own code. For example, as far as I know, Arduino declares its standard library in the global namespace. This only becomes a problem if two libraries claim the same namespace without respecting one anothers declarations. You are unlikely to get the author to change the namespace if this is not a very small library, because it will break all existing code using it.

Comment: @walnut in the case of Arduino it is understandable (it's more like an entire ecosystem on it's own). In fact the affected library is a breakout-board manufacturer, so this is kinda related probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Remark] For future readers:

Please review the comments, as they reflect better the full picture of the answer.
The following answer by @[Baruch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331785) gives you a quick-fix to the situation.
But as suggested in the comments this **might** be a poor design choice by authors of an external library.

### Original answer by @Baruch:

You should put your code in a namespace, not the external code

```
#include "some/sensor.h"

namespace MyLib {
  class Sensor {
   private:
    ::Sensor s; /* use foreign object as member */
   public:
    Sensor();
    void init(unsigned char p);
  };
}
```

The link errors are caused by the fact that you essentially declared a new type, `Lib::Sensor`, which is not defined anywhere. The class defined in `some/sensor.cpp` is `Sensor`, not `Lib::Sensor`

Comment: but that would mean, that once a name is defined in an external library, that very same name can't be used as an identifier in my own code, without using a namespace? So, I can't just use "Sensor" as an identifier, just because the external library reserved that name and is now preventing me from using the same (understandable and very readable) name?

Comment: @m0r0n If a library declares some fully qualified name with external linkage, like `::Sensor` in your example, then you will not be able to use the same name in the same namespace scope again for something else. There is no way of doing that. This is why it is not a good idea for a library to put their declarations into the global namespace. The library should use a library-specific namespace instead. You would need to add `namespace Lib { ...}` around the definitions in every source file of the library as well to force it to use a different fully qualified name.

Comment: @walnut ok, so if I understand your point right, it's a bad design choice by the authors of the library, right?

Comment: @m0r0n Yes, assuming it is actually a C++ library (as your example code suggests). C libraries are different, because there are no namespaces in C (but then in C usually the library adds a prefix to the names it declares with external linkage to avoid clashes).